# How to align table and caption when table is centered on page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I haven't been able to figure out the best way to set up my tables. These are the features that they are supposed to have:

1. Should be centered on page
2. Caption should be "justified" and aligned with left border of the table. If caption spans over two line, then line should break at right border of the table.
3. Additional comments should stand between caption and top border of table, and should as well be "justified" and aligned with left border of the table. If the additional comments contain a second line, it should break at the right border of the table.

To clarify I included two examples in the following code. The first is exactly what my tables are supposed to look like. It works only, because the table is so wide, that there are no other possibilities for alignments and line breaks. The second table just does not follow rule #2 and #3 as stated above. Does anyone have an idea how to solve these two problems?

Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage[format=hang,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}[2004/07/16]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\commenttable}[1]{\par{\itshape #1\par}\vskip 2mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table caption with a really fancy and ridiculously long description of what could and also should be said in just a few words}
\commenttable{Hello. \blindtext.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSSSSSSS}
\toprule
{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}\\
\midrule
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34&12.34&12.34  \\
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34&12.34&12.34  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table caption with a really fancy and ridiculously long description of what could and also should be said in just a few words}
\commenttable{Hello. \blindtext.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSSSS}
\toprule
{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}\\
\midrule
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  \\
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the `caption` and the `floatrow` packages. Your `commenttable` command has to be put in the first argument of the `ttabbox` command, just after `caption{…}`. To have a correct vertical spacing, I had to modify it slighly.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage[format=hang,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}[2004/07/16]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\commenttable}[1]{\vskip2ex\par{\itshape #1}}%\par\vskip 2mm

        \usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
        \usepackage{floatrow}  

       \DeclareCaptionFormat{leftmargin}{\captionsetup{textfont={small, md, up}, labelfont={small, sf, md, up}, labelsep=space, position = above, slc = off}\textls*[150]{\MakeUppercase{#1 #2}}#3}%
       \captionsetup{format = leftmargin}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{table}
\centering
\ttabbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{A table caption with a really fancy and ridiculously long description of what could and also should be said in just a few words\commenttable{Hello. \blindtext.}}}
{%
  \begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSSSSSSS}
\toprule
{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}\\
\midrule
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34&12.34&12.34  \\
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34&12.34&12.34  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{table}
\ttabbox{\caption{A table caption with a really fancy and ridiculously long description of what could and also should be said in just a few words\commenttable{Hello. \blindtext.}}}%
{%
\begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSSSS}
\toprule
{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}\\
\midrule
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  \\
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is tailor made for the `boxhandler` package, which sets captions in the style you asked, almost by default.  The captioning is configurable.  However, one must enter the table as a macro `\bxtable{caption}{content}`, not an environment, which some people will find bothersome.

The only challenge was to align the comment with the table automagically.  To do that, I set the `tabular` in a temporary box, and made the comment in a `\parbox` of that width, and stacked it above the `tabular` box.

Also, because the image is rotated, the maximum allowable caption width has to be reset (I initially thought this a package bug until I realized what was going on).

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage[format=hang,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}[2004/07/16]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
% Need to reset max caption width, because of rotated image
\constrainCaptionWidth[1in]{\linewidth}
% Make caption flush with outer edge of table content
\setlength{\TableDeadMargin}{0em}
\bxtable{%
A table caption with a really fancy and ridiculously long description of 
what could and also should be said in just a few words}{%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSSSS}
\toprule
{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}&{column}\\
\midrule
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  \\
12.34   &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  &12.34  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
\setstackgap{S}{12pt}%
\Shortstack{\parbox{\wd0}{\itshape Hello \blindtext}\\ \box0}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does exactly what I need. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution that worked fine
for me without any special packages or advanced latex tricks, etc.
The idea is just to put the tabular and caption inside minipage with sufficient width and then add such space with \hspace before the minipage to shift it to more central horisontal position with almost equal distance from left and right margins of the text.

```
\begin{table}[...]
\hspace{0.05\textwidth} 
\begin{minipage}{0.94\linewidth}
\caption{...}
\label{...}
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```